# C# handling data between a DataSet and a ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, dataset

I've had a look on the Internet and, whilst I have come across some content which is similar, I can't seem to find something which is directly related to what I'm trying to achieve.

Briefly, I want to achieve the following:

1) Extract data from a database into a DataSet;
2) Populate data which uses ONE of the columns of information from the DataSet;
3) Use the OnIndexChanged event to trigger a component on a form to display the corresponding values of the dataset in other columns as to what is displayed in the ListBox.

I am running a query which returns the following results:

[image]

Having loaded this into a DataSet within C#, I want to populate a ListBox with the values in the 'ADDRESS' column.

When selecting a record in that ListBox after populating it, I want a label caption on the form to display the corresponding ADDRESS_ID value associated with that ADDRESS record.

I hope that outlines what I want to achieve in enough detail; what I've found so far is great for populating a list box but I'm stuck after this point when trying to reverse-engineer another value based on the selected index of the ListBox.

Comment: This is a lot to read through, but check it out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Comment: Instead of a ListBox, I'd suggest using a DataGridView and bind your dataset to that. It's much easier to manage and you have a vast range of options for handling your change events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listbox1.DataSource=AddressTable; {Datatable}
listbox1.DisplayMember="Address";
listbox1.ValueMember="Address_ID";
```

then onchange event

```
label1.Text = ((DataRowView) listBox1.SelectedItem)["Address_ID"].ToString();
```

Comment: Many thanks; worked like a charm (once the DataTable was populated)

Answer (score 0):

use a list with all the address values (i assume there are never any duplicates?)

on form load or whatever to build the list and populate the listbox.

```
List<string> addresses = new List<string>();

foreach(datarow r in MyDataset)
    addresses.add(r["Address"].ToString());

listbox1.datasource = addresses;
```

then in the onchange event for the listbox

```
foreach(datarow r in MyDataset)
{
    if(r["address"].ToString() == listbox1.selectedvalue)
        label1.text = r["Address_ID"].ToString();
}
```